# How can I get Control Inside DatGridView columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can i get Controls like CheckBox in DataGridViewCheckBoxCell similarly combobox in DataGridViewComboBoxCell ?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPerformance.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[6];
   //I need to find CheckBox in chk
}
```

Comment: so basically, you want a heterogeneous column with different controls in different rows of the same column right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is possible to access the editing control of the grid, but this isn't usually very useful (there is only one editing control for all the cells in the grid of a certain type).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a `CheckBox` control from a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, but you can get its value:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPerformance.Rows){
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[6] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

   if(chk != null && (bool)chk.Value){
      //checked, do something
   }
}
```